# Android - Binding adapter failed to load a text

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, retrofit, android-databinding

I write simple app displaying cocktails list. The problem is there's no title text but the pics is loading with picasso working just fine. I suppose the weak point in my Binding Adapter. Cause I can't just pass data value, i need to pass data?.list and I am really confused why I can't. Please help!
[The app result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOemJ.png)

CocktailListFragment.kt

```
class CocktailListFragment : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: CocktailListViewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProvider(this).get(CocktailListViewModel::class.java)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val binding = CocktailListFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        binding.cocktail = viewModel
        binding.cocktailList.adapter = CocktailListAdapter()

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.filter_menu, menu)
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    }
}
```

CocktailListViewModel.kt

```
class CocktailListViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _cocktails = MutableLiveData<CocktailsList>()
    val cocktails: LiveData<CocktailsList>
        get() = _cocktails

    private var viewModelJob = Job()
    private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(viewModelJob + Dispatchers.Main)

    init {
        getCocktails()
    }

    private fun getCocktails() {
        coroutineScope.launch {
            val getCocktailsDeferred = CocktailsApi.RETROFIT_SERVICE.getCocktailsAsync()
            try {
                val result = getCocktailsDeferred.await()
                _cocktails.value = result
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d("error", "error")
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        viewModelJob.cancel()
    }
}
```

CocktailListAdapter.kt

```
class CocktailListAdapter :
    ListAdapter<Cocktail, CocktailListAdapter.CocktailListViewHolder>(DiffCallback) {


    class CocktailListViewHolder(private var binding: CocktailItemBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(cocktail: Cocktail) {
            binding.cocktail = cocktail
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CocktailListViewHolder {
        return CocktailListViewHolder(CocktailItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CocktailListViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val cocktail = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(cocktail)
    }

    companion object DiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Cocktail>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Cocktail, newItem: Cocktail): Boolean {
            return oldItem === newItem
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Cocktail, newItem: Cocktail): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }
    }
}
```

CocktailDataClass

```
data class CocktailsList(
    @SerializedName("drinks")
    val list: List<Cocktail>
)

data class Cocktail (
    @SerializedName("idDrink")
    val id: String,
    @SerializedName("strDrinkThumb")
    val drinkImg: String,
    @SerializedName("strDrink")
    val drinkTitle: String
)
```

BindingAdapters - I think the problem is in binding adapter for list data:

```
@BindingAdapter("listData")
fun bindRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView, data: CocktailsList?) {
    val adapter = recyclerView.adapter as CocktailListAdapter
    adapter.submitList(data?.list)
}

@BindingAdapter("strDrinkThumb")
fun bindImage(imgView: ImageView, imgUrl: String?) {
    imgUrl?.let {
        val imgUri = imgUrl.toUri().buildUpon().scheme("https").build()
        Picasso.get()
            .load(imgUri)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_animation)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_broken_image)
            .into(imgView)
    }
}
```

cocktail_list_fragemnt.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="cocktail"
            type="com.example.coctaildb.cocktaillist.CocktailListViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="30dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                app:menu="@menu/filter_menu"
                app:title="@string/drinks"
                app:titleTextColor="@android:color/black" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/cocktail_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/appBarLayout2"
            app:listData="@{cocktail.cocktails}"
            tools:listitem="@layout/cocktail_item" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

cocktail_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="cocktail"
            type="com.example.coctaildb.network.Cocktail" />
    </data>


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cocktail_img"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:maxHeight="100dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:strDrinkThumb="@{cocktail.drinkImg}"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cocktail_title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"

            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"

            android:text="@{cocktail.drinkTitle}"
            android:textColor="#7E7E7E"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cocktail_img"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Just change your display text color 

You are using a dark background and by default display text color also dark.

Comment: Oh it wasn't the problem with text color it was constraint layout in the item. Thank you, your answer helped me to pay attention on the item layout